How to ensure that reporting data loads don't get impacted during the incremental ETL loading the tables?
I have developed an ETL to load data from oltp database to another database (let's call it DWDb). The ETL stages data and loads it into the final table.
Every one hour I perform an incremental load by truncating staging table, loading the staging table with changes since last 7 days (as existing data can change), and then doing an update/insert on the final table based on the key.
When the reporting application fetches the data from the DWDb, and during that time if the incremental load is running, I am observing 2 issues:

blocking of either the etl or the reporting application query. Is there a solution like sp_rename or partition switching to handle this?

inconsistent data wherein some tables have latest data and some don't yet have latest data. A possible solution for this is to use entire load inside a transaction?


What are my options to allow the reporting application to fetch consistent data across all tables, without blocking?
For a full load I understand there are solutions like partition switching, schema switching, table renaming to ensure minimum downtime. I'm looking for some pattern that is followed to handle this in an incremental load scenario.

Schema "swapping" could be an option. There's a lot of information out there already on this sort of thing; what about the content didn't you understand, or why do you feel they weren't suitable to your needs?

You can use Partition switching to quickly load your table from an identical stage table, even if you don't use partitions, one can switch on partition 0 to achieve same effect. See for example: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/using-switch-on-a-single-partition

I can understand using this approach for full loads. But how do I use this for incremental load?

You can do the schema/table swapping for incremental load too. Basically, you have two copies of the final table, you can work on one, then rename them and then work on the other. A lot of people use stuff like separate database and log shipping/replication/mirroring for the reporting part though

By copy do you mean select * into temp_final_table from final_table?

No, I don't, that doesn't sounds like a incremental load. First, you create a second table, TableCopy or whatever. You copy all data from your Production table. Now, they're in sync. When you need to do a new load, you first sync all the data with the copy table, by doing DELETE/INSERT/UPDATE or MERGE. When you're done, you rename the prod table to a temporary name and rename the copy table into prod table in some sort of exclusive lock. Now, you do the same DELETE/INSERT/UPDATE/MERGE thing with the temporary prod table, and when you're done, you can rename them back.

I don't get the purpose of the last part: Now, you do the same DELETE/INSERT/UPDATE/MERGE thing with the temporary prod table, and when you're done, you can rename them back. can you help me understand please why we need 3 copies of the table (prod, copy, temp)

You need two tables, not three. ProdTable and ProdTableCopy. Then you "merge" the copy, then Rename ProdTable to ProdTableX and ProdTableCopy to ProdTable. Then you fix ProdTableX. Then you rename ProdTable to ProdTableCopy and ProdTableX to ProdTable. Etc

I assume you're saying Merge the ProdTableCopy to keep it up-to-date with the ProdTable. Then update the ProdTableCopy with the data from source (update/insert). Then switch (sp_rename) both tables?
